# Is it harmful constantly switching back and forth between Operating Systems?

Tags: operating-systems, desktop-computer, storage

I have heard of a few interesting operating systems a while ago, and I wanted to install them on my small PC to experiment with them, but i'm worried about possible side effects, if there are even any. I have heard that if you constantly load a bunch of data in a storage medium, its lifespan might get shortened, which I don't really know if it's true or not, but besides that, is there anything else I might need to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you can run into is hibernation.  If you hibernate an OS, some data will be saved in a memory image and not saved to its final place on disk.  The idea is that it is much faster to read in a memory image than to restart all your apps.  If you boot a different OS and try to use the same filesystems, you will end up corrupting the data if you then restart the hibernated OS.  As long as you use separate disk space for each OS, you are ok.

Comment: I'm not sure about Linux, but with Windows it's not an issue. When Windows is hibernated all NTFS partitions are marked read-only and Linux respects this.

Comment: The problem is if you want to use the filesystems in the alternate OS.  You have to know not to remount them R/W.

Comment: As I said, Linux will mount hibernated Windows volumes read-only unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

SSD drives indeed wear out when they are written to. They are pretty tough though, a modern SSD should last years with dozens of GB written to them every day. You can check the MTBF value in manufacturer's specs of your specific SSD if you have one.

For HDDs reads/writes don't seem to affect device's lifespan significantly or at least in a predictable manner.

(No matter what kind of disk you have, you should have backups. Random failures happen to all kinds of hardware.)

For experimentation I'd suggest using virtual machines rather than installing to bare metal. This way you don't risk damaging your main OS while partitioning or changing boot configuration. VMs are entirely self-contained and don't "leak" to host's OS configuration. The data is still stored on your disk, so the SSD wear problem is still present, but rather than directly on disk all data is contained in a file which acts as a virtual disk, thus isolating the VM from host.

My virtualization solution of choice is VirtualBox, but there's also the free VMware Player and if you have a Pro version of Windows, you can give Hyper-V a try.